# No. of times determinant function would be used to determine the rank of A (m x n ) matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have been given A(m × n)  matrix. And I have to identify upper bound on the number of times
the determinant function would be used to determine the rank of this matrix.

Options are given as below :-

a) mCm + mC(m-1) + ….. + mC2 for a case

b) mCn

c) nCm

d) nCn + nC(n-1) + ….. + nC2 for a case

I have attempted it and as per my knowledge there are two options which are correct a) and b). But not completely sure.

Comment: Are you using a certain algorithm to determine the rank of the matrix?

Comment: What do you mean by "for a case"?  How are (a) or (b) correct?

Comment: Perhaps it was assumed that $m\ge n$?  This was not stated in your Question, though of course we can arrange it (by taking the transpose of $A$ if necessary).

Comment: @RobertIsrael for a case is for only one case.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, we can assume that ≥.

Answer (score 2):

If the rank is $r$, there is a nonzero $r \times r$ minor, but no $(r+1) \times (r+1)$.  In the worst case, there is only one nonzero $r \times r$ minor.  You might be able to get clues to which $r \times r$ minors to look at if most of the $(r-1) \times (r-1)$ minors are $0$, but I see no reason that you couldn't have all $(r-1) \times (r-1)$ minors nonzero.  So then, even if you know the rank must be $r$ or $r-1$, you would have to check
at least all $r \times r$ minors, which is ${m \choose r}{n \choose r}$.  If $m = n$ and $r = n/2$, that's likely to be more than any of your choices.